# Show form below the selected row

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a table with a few entries and each entry can get edited (form appears). But when I click on "edit" the form shows always below the whole table. I want that it always appears below the selected the row. How can I achieve that? There is a bug in my code but I don't see it:

```
class MyList extends Component {

//...Code
_editPolicy=(id)=>{
    this.form()
}

form = (e) => {…}

render () {
    return (
        <div className="container">
                <div className="col-sm-8 mx-auto">
                    <h2 className="text-center">Table</h2>
                </div>
                <table class="table caption-top">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Type</th>
                        <th scope="col">Object</th>
                        <th scope="col">Creation Date</th>
                        <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                        <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                        <th scope="col"> Add </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                            <td> - </td>
                            <td> 
                                <ActionSelector
                                    options={actionTypes}
                                    setSelected={this.setSelectedType}
                                />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <ActionSelector
                                    options={actions}
                                    setSelected={this.setSelectedAction}
                                />
                            </td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td><button onClick={this.onSubmit} className="btn btn-success" type="submit">+</button></td>
                        </tr>
                { this.state.actions.map((action,index) => {
                        return (
                            <React.Fragment key={index}>
                                <tr>
                                <th scope="row">{index}</th>
                                <td>{action.actionType.label}</td>
                                <td>{action.description}</td>
                                <td>{action.creation}</td>
                                <td><button onClick={this._edit.bind(this, action['_id'])} class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">edit</button></td>
                                <td><button onClick={this._delete.bind(this, action.action_id)} class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">delete</button></td>
                                <td> -</td>
                                </tr>
                            </React.Fragment>
                        )
                    }
                )}
                </tbody>
                </table>
                {this.state.new_row.type.value === „Edit“ ? (
                <div>
                    {this.form(this.state.new_row)}
                </div>) : (
        )}
        </div>
    )
}}
```

I only posted the most relevant code. If you need more, then I can post my whole class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 things:

1. a variable to keep the index of the row in which the current edit button is selected.
2. Move the logic to render form to the section you render actions via that .map function:

```
  constructor() {
    this.onEdit.bind(this);
    ...
  }
  
// in onEdit function:
  onEdit(curIndex) {
    ...
    this.setState({editingIndex: curIndex});
  }
...
  { this.state.actions.map((action, index) => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment key={index}>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">{index}</th>
          <td>{action.actionType.label}</td>
          <td>{action.description}</td>
          <td>{action.creation}</td>
          <td><button onClick={() => this.onEdit(index)} >edit</button></td>
          <td><button onClick={...}>delete</button></td>
          <td> -</td>
        </tr>
        {this.state.editingIndex === index ? (
          <tr><td>{this.form(this.state.new_row)}</td></tr>) : null}                           
      </React.Fragment>
  )
}}
```

In above we pass the current row index to the `onEdit` method. So, when the edit button is clicked we now know which index (which row) it was.
Then in the render section (`this.state.actions.map`) we compare the index of each row we render with the index of the row we pressed the edit button on. If these 2 match, we render the form right below that row.

your code is very in complete, and has too much noise in it, hence I put code snippets instead of a full answer.
I recommend you create a simpler table with only 2 columns and only an edit button, so that you get better answers.

I highly recommend you make yourself familiar with a few things:

1. instead of `class` components use hook (`useState`).
2. Make sure your html is valid (inside table do not use div, only use it as child of a `<td>` or `<th>` element.

Comment: Is it possible to hide and show this row while I click on the "edit" button?

Comment: yep of course, add a state variable which is true by default, whenever edit is pressed set it to false and switch back to true when edit is finished